# How to get the command command behind gui action?

Tags: windows, user-interface, cmd, location, directory

I need to **change** the **location** of the desktop **folder** using the **command** **promt**. I know how to do this using the **gui**. What is the **command** behind changing the desktop folder location?

Note: I **dont** want to use *AutoHotKey* to automate the gui action.

Extra info: I want to have multiple workspaces on one account. I want all the files to stay at the same position, just change the directory of the desktop. For example I have two folders ../documents/desktopA and ../documents/DesktopB. I just want to chose what folder is the desktop while not changing the content inside folders.

Comment: Never heard of that. Gui actions are pretty much internal. it exposes hot keys but that's pretty much it.

Comment: and you also dont know how to change the location of the desktop folder using the command promt?

Comment: Your question is meaningless. Programs don't type commands meant for users.

Comment: I removed that part of the question. But I believe there is a way to do all gui functions with the command promt instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a lot. But you can't match GUI to command prompt.

Here's a VBScript  that looks up desktop folder.

```
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
With ShellApp
MsgBox .Namespace(&h10).Title & vbcrlf & .Namespace(&h10).self.path & vbcrlf & "( " & GetShName(.Namespace(&h10).self.path) & " )" & vbcr & vbcrlf & .Namespace(&h19).Title & vbcrlf & .Namespace(&h19).self.path & vbcrlf & "( " & GetShName(.Namespace(&h19).self.path) & " )" & vbcr & vbcrlf & .Namespace(&h0).Title & vbcrlf &  .Namespace(&h0).self.path & vbcrlf  & "( " & GetShName(.Namespace(&h10).self.path) & " )" , 64, "Check IE's Paths"
End With

Function GetShName(folderspec)
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
   GetShName = f.ShortPath
End Function
```

There is no command to change Desktop. You can rewrite it's storage.

See `Reg /?` and `reg add /?`. The key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was already looking in the registry, but was expecting it to be in the same place as the icon positions are saved. I just want to change the position of the desktop folder, but not its content. this is all i need.

Comment: I tried this out, but it didnt work for some reason. I created a .reg file that contains this: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders]
"Desktop"="C:\\Users\\MultiDesQ\\Documents\\DesktopB"  . I have a DesktopA and a DesktopB folder in my documents folder. When I run the .reg file it doesn update the link inside the registry, but it doesn't actually change the folder location. When I use the gui it still sais that the location is../documents/desktopA . Even If I press f5 or restart the explorer.

Comment: This isn't helpful. GUI programs and console programs will call the same Windows' API (Application Programming Interface). However you'd need substantial knowledge to write your own programs that can call API functions. Batch file can't. Nor can VBScript.

Comment: You have to kill `explorer.exe` and restart it. See **Ctrl + Shift + Escape** to do this. The registry is read at program startup.

Comment: I did that, use that also when I use the gui to change the map. It didnt seem to work.

Comment: Maybe try `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Explorer\Shell Folders` but the original key seems the most recent.

Comment: I'm a total spoon. I looked at that folder in stead of the origional. The origional .reg file is a hexadecimal file, but ill check if i can get it to work

Comment: Why are you doing this? Windows has it's own multi desktop feature built in. Right click a blank spot on taskbar, make sure *Show Task Button* is checked. The button is next to *Start*.

Comment: I know you can have multiple desktops, but you cant have different desktop icons on the same layout. For example I want to have my gaming shortcuts on one virtual desktop and have my school icons on a different desktop. I will use that feature too.

Comment: I got it working now, succesfully changed the desktop location using the registry. Thanks for the help